# Entity framework migration not detecting any changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I was running successfully `Entity framework 6.0.0-alpha3` until today. Today I decided to update to `Entity framework 6.0.0-rc1`, and as specified [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/05/30/ef6-beta-1-available.aspx) in order to run my migrations I need to remove all the previous migrations made by `ef alpha1-alpha3` and remake them.

Since all my migrations were made by `alpha3`, I decided to drop all the migrations (including _MigrationHistory table), and re-enable it.

I created initial migration with `add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges` (which has empty `Up()` and `Down()` methods), then I executed `update-database`, and I thought, that everything is okay. Well, its not. When I am adding new class to my model, `add-migration first` creates migration with empty `Up()` and `Down()` methods.

Also, previously, when I wanted to access object that wasn't yet registered with migrations, I was receiving an error saying that I need to update my migrations. Now, when I try to access the new object, it simply says `"Invalid object name 'dbo.Notifications'."`.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 7):

EF uses a snapshot of the database model (which is saved along with the migration) to determine changes between current version of your database model and the last migration.

`add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges` command creates a migration with the snapshot of your database model, but it ignores any changes from previous database snapshot (i.e. empty database) because you are telling to do so.

`add-migration First` command looks at previous migration (i.e. Initial) and compares the current database model snapshot with the snapshot form the `Initial` migration. Obviously these snapshots are the same, so `Up()` and `Down()` methods are empty.

I think the solution for your problem is to generate all changes in the Initial migration

`add-migration Initial`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an issue where entity was not recognizing my changes, even if I added a completely new entity class to the assembly it would still not see it.

I just reverted to a migration when I remember everything was okay, deleted all migration files after that migration, and ran Add-Migration again. Then finally all the combined changes showed up.

Comment: Just to add to this, I encountered the issue again and this time the only thing that solved it is doing a "Batch Build" (with rebuild). It's under the Debug menu I believe. Note this isn't the same as a place Rebuild as that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue.  Ended up deleting all tables from DB, including EFMigrationHistory, then deleting migrations folder from my solution.
Finally did Batch build step with rebuild mentioned in other comment.  Nothing worked till i did batch build.  I am running latest release of VS 2017 as of 11/18/18

Answer (score 0):

I also had empty up/down and the cause was EF didn't like that my models had [JsonProperty] above their properties, sinceI used the same models for a json datasource as well.

Comment: Are you sure? Never noticed any interference with this attribute. Please show details as to when the attribute causes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There are following steps which help me achieve my goal.

1. Delete added migration file from Migrations folder
2. run `remove-migration` in Package Manager Console
3. run `add-migration` with comment
4. run `update-database`

That's it. Best of luck.